# Media buttons on keyboard not working on Windows 8.1 Preview

Tags: keyboard, fn-key, windows-8.1-preview

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 Preview and now my media buttons on my keyboard (Qpad MK-50) (FN + F1-6) is not working.

Tested with foobar2000, Windows Media Player, VLC and MPC HC.

Any ideas how I can get it to work again?

Answer (score 0):

- Download drivers [here](http://www.qpad.com/products/keyboards/mk-85/#support) for your device

Comment: I have MK-50. It doesn't have any drivers or special functions that MK-85 have.

Comment: try HotKeyz at www.skynergy.com/hotkeyz.html‎ or using http://www.autohotkey.com/ => to send windows 8 (play,pause) global hotkeys